# Get Size of web resource with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a way to get the size (in bytes) of a web resource ( page, static content, binary etc ) without having to download the file with python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) to get the byte size of an object:

> sys.getsizeof(object[, default]):
>
> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of
> object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this
> does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is
> implementation specific.
>
> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is
> accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.
> ...

```
import requests as req
import sys

resp = req.get("http://www.example.com") #Getting the site
print(sys.getsizeof(resp))
```

Answer (score 0):

@krmogi 's answer is not correct and it always returns 48 for me

this will work:

```
import requests as re

res = re.get(URL)
print(len(res.content)) # in bytes
```